# Where to throw the exception in the insert method of a linked list

Tags: java, exception

I have an insert method here that is supposed to throw a ListOverFlowException when the linked list cannot add any more nodes. I don't know where in the code I can throw the exception.

```
public void insert(D data) throws ListOverflowException {
    Node<D> iterator = new Node<>(data);

    if(startOfNode == null) {       
        startOfNode = iterator;   
        endOfNode = iterator;      
        iterator.setNext(startOfNode); 
    }

    endOfNode.setNext(iterator); 
    endOfNode = iterator;      
    endOfNode.setNext(startOfNode); 
                                       
    
    // where do I put the ListOverflowException?
    //throw new ListOverflowException("Error! Can't add any more nodes");

    sizeOfList++; // updates the size of the node
}
```

Comment: Do you have a max size or length configured?

Comment: None. My instructor said that I need to throw the exception just in case the method cannot insert any more nodes.

Comment: Throw it before you make any modifications to the list. This is called "failure atomicity".

Comment: @Manji why would you not be able to insert more nodes if there is no maximum size?

Comment: I see. I thought that there might be some limit on how many nodes that can be linked. Now I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When does the method cannot insert any more nodes?

You should have a `maxSize` value in your list (either hard coded or passed to the constructor of your class).

Then you can use it to check against the `sizeOfList`.

```
class YourLinkedList<D> {
    private Node<D> startOfNode, endOfNode;
    private int sizeOfList;
    private int maxSize;

    //Passing max size 
    public YourLinkedList(int size) {
        this.maxSize = size;
    }
    
    ....

    public void insert(D data) throws ListOverflowException {
        if (sizeOfList == maxSize) {
            throw new ListOverflowException("Error! Can't add any more nodes");
        }
        //your current code
    }
}
```

Or you can just make it a constant.

```
class YourLinkedList {
   private int maxSize = 10;
  //rest of code
}
```